# Maximo: Show user's assigned workflow work orders in map

Tags: configuration, gis, geospatial, maximo, ticket-system

A user has multiple **workflow** work orders assigned to them in the Start Center:

[image]

I want the user to be able to click a button (or link) in the Start Center that will:

1. Open a Maximo map (Maximo Spatial).
2. Show the assigned work orders on the map.
3. Allow the user to click a work order on the map, which will open the work order in the Work Order Tracking application.

**How can I configure Maximo to do this?**

*Maximo 7.6.1.1*

Comment: Do you have a more reproducible example?

Comment: Related: [Maximo: Mimic Workflow assignments with an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57938379/10936066)