# Jython: Open URL in browser (without importing Python libraries)

Tags: java, url, browser, jython, maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

Using Jython, I want to open a URL in a browser (in Windows 10).

I've found a [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226244/10936066):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
}
```

And I've attempted to convert it to Jython:

```
from java.awt import Desktop
from java.net import URI

desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()
uri = URI("http://google.com/#q=wonum1%2Cwonum2%2Cwonum3")
desktop.browse(uri)
```

While the Jython does compile successfully, it does **not** open the browser.

---

**How can I open a URL in a browser using Jython?**

Comment: Your Jython code works for me (Jython 2.7.1, Java 12.0.2, Windows 10). The URL opens in Firefox as expected.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks. I'm new to this stuff. I found this blurb in [the docs](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/scripting_with_maximo6?lang=en): *"It is important to understand that the Automation scripts are a server-side artifact, as opposed to a client-side one. So all your scripts are executed on the server side as opposed to say in the browser."* **Is it relevant?**

Comment: It might be. I have never used Maximo and I know nothing about it.

Comment: This script would run server side.  You could have it return a response and have some javascript process the response into opening a url, but I think that defeats your purpose.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the Launch in Context feature doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: @JPTremblay I would like the user to be able to click a button in the WO list view that would open a URL that has the selected WOs IDs as parameters. I don't think I understand how this would be done with Launch in Context. Is there a way?

Comment: @User1973 Is this related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937719/maximo-show-users-assigned-workflow-work-orders-in-map
My understanding is that the Launch in Context feature needs a record (mbo) as the "context" to pull data from to build an URL. In your case the context would be the list tab result set (mboset) so your use case is quite different. Did you try Preacher's alternative solution to use an automation script that would feed a non-persistent attribute that would contain the concatenated params string built from iterating the mboset?

Comment: Hi @JPTremblay, it's related to this question: [WO List View: Execute URL with list of WONUMS](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=793a809a-340c-435f-bc95-aa09a61cd24e&ps=25). And yes, I've come up with a script that iterates the mboset. An action displays a URL in an error message, which the user can copy and paste into the browser. However, I'd prefer it if the action could simply open the URL in the browser automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The short answer

"You can't." Or, more accurately, "It's probably not worth the effort / risk."

## The long answer

From previous experience, using VB to write CGI (which I do NOT recommend), I would guess that putting the code from your question in an automation script might cause a browser session to get launched on the server, where your script was run. Things may have changed since those VB days, 20+ years ago, but I would still be tempted to check.

@Milton was on the right track, I think, but with Maximo it would actually be a little more complicated. This is because when he said, "You could have [the script] return a response", that response would be returned from the business logic layer on the server side to the UI layer on the server side which would then have to return it to the browser, which you would have had to "big C" customize Maximo to expect that response and know what to do with it.

## The alternative

You could maybe return an error from your script, and have the message include a URL. Or use an Autoscript + Conditional UI + Launch in Context + Nonpersistent Attribute mix to expose a link for the user to click.

Comment: Agree with 99% of what you are saying here.  
One bad idea I would call a middle case c customization because it still doesn't require java development and recompile.  You can make a custom JSP and call the javascript to do this in the JSP.  Call the JSP in the application xml.  Downside, everytime someone modifies the application (in my experience) they will delete your JSP call or when they upgrade maximo your registration of the JSP in the xml files will get deleted.

Comment: @milton Thank you for the clarification. Good point. JSP customization is often overlooked, though this is probably a good thing given your experience.

Comment: @Milton and Preacher: [Steven Shull on DevWorks says,](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c93dd0d1-47fb-4883-8609-c260eb29c91b&ps=25) *"In 7.6.1.2, they are planning to support opening a URL from an Automation Script..."*. This sounds great for people who will have 7.6.1.2! (not me)

Answer (score 3):

As some have have indicated, automation scripts in Maximo are run on the server side. These scripts are setup based on certain types of launch points to activate when the script will run on the server side. In general the automation scripts can not really be used to manipulate the UI elements because these are controlled on the webclient layer.

What launch point type was used with the example Jython code above? It might work if it were an action type launch point associated with a push button in the UI. But I am unsure the context for how and when you are wanting this action to occur. But more than likely it still would not work because the Java code is still being run from the server side and not the client. Typically, you would have to create a custom Java class file extention for the application to add to the webclient layer. Though most organizations try to stay away from these type of true customizations because of the issues it can cause with future updates and upgrades to the base Maximo product.

Maximo has an out of the box functionality built in that allows a user to launch in context URLs. Here is an IBM link that has a pdf of an example of launching an address associated from a record in Maximo into Google Maps.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a#fullpageWidgetId=W5f281fe58c09_49c7_9fa4_e094f86b7e98&file=a6af8bfb-8b72-4b57-945c-786ab4d71b14

Also I am not sure exactly what the purpose is for the requirement. But I have also seen were if you were just trying to retrieve information from an external source you can actually display the information directly in the Maximo application if the external web application can be access through a webservice type interaction.